# Pandas rolling time window distinct count with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So, I have a dataframe like this:

```
A,B,C,D
foo,something,2019-01-04 09:56:01,True
bar,something,2019-01-05 8:15:09,True
bar,something,2019-01-05 10:15:10,False
bar,something,2019-01-07 10:15:10,False
baz,something,2019-02-07 10:15:38,True
bar,somethingelse,2019-02-09 11:42:16,False
foo,something,2019-05-04 11:44:56,True
foobar,something,2019-07-15 13:23:09,True
foo,something,2019-08-04 11:44:56,False
foobar,something,2019-08-05 13:23:09,False
foobarbaz,something,2019-08-05 13:23:10,True
```

And I want to compute 2 new columns:

Firstly, the number of previous distinct values of "A" within a rolling window of time (let's say 2 days) where the value for "B" is the same as that of the row in consideration (including the row in consideration in the count).

Secondly, the number of previous distinct values of "A" within the same rolling window of time where the value for "B" is the same as that of the current row AND the value for "D" is "True".

The desired output would thus be:

```
A,B,C,D,F,G
foo,something,2019-01-04 09:56:01,True,1,1
bar,something,2019-01-05 8:15:09,True,2,2
bar,something,2019-01-05 10:15:10,False,2,2
bar,something,2019-01-07 10:15:10,False,1,1,0
baz,something,2019-02-07 10:15:38,True,1,1
bar,somethingelse,2019-02-09 11:42:16,False,1,0
foo,something,2019-05-04 11:44:56,True,1,1,1
foobar,something,2019-07-15 13:23:09,True,1,1
foo,something,2019-08-04 11:44:56,False,1,0
foobar,something,2019-08-05 13:23:09,False,2,0
foobarbaz,something,2019-08-05 13:23:10,True,3,1
```

For the first part (computing column F), my answer is:

```
df["F"] = pd.factorize(df["A"])[0]
result = df.groupby("B").rolling("2D", on="C").F.apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)))
```

Which I then can re-merge into the df on columns B and C (the datetimes in C are all distinct). It gives the desired results.

But for column G, I can't find a solution. Filtering the df (df.loc[df.D]) prior to applying the same two lines as above is not a correct solution, as a row where "D" is "False" can still have prior rows for which it is "True".
The output obtained by that method (post-merge) is therefore:

```
A,B,C,D,F,G
foo,something,2019-01-04 09:56:01,True,1,1
bar,something,2019-01-05 8:15:09,True,2,2
bar,something,2019-01-05 10:15:10,False,2,NaN
bar,something,2019-01-07 10:15:10,False,1,1,NaN
baz,something,2019-02-07 10:15:38,True,1,1
bar,somethingelse,2019-02-09 11:42:16,False,1,NaN
foo,something,2019-05-04 11:44:56,True,1,1
foobar,something,2019-07-15 13:23:09,True,1,1
foo,something,2019-08-04 11:44:56,False,1,NaN
foobar,something,2019-08-05 13:23:09,False,2,NaN
foobarbaz,something,2019-08-05 13:23:10,True,3,1
```

The non-NaN values are correct, but I can't just fillna() those NaNs (compare with desired output), so the approach seems flawed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why does your input data have all `NaN` in column `E`?

Comment: Removed an irrelevant column before submitting, forgot to remove the headers. Fixed.